# knitr button in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I'm a beginner to R and Rstudio. One of my first problems is that I do not have the knitr option in rstudio, despite having installed the knitr package. I have checked and I do have the last version of Rstudio. I am aware of how dumb this question is, but I can't but ask it after I tried everything. Shockingly, I have the knitr option/button at work, where Rstudio was installed in the same fashion (apparently). I'm attaching a screenshot of my rstudio. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Side note: You really shouldn't have to specify lib.loc every time you load a package.  Is there a reason you're doing it that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently don't have your file saved with a standard extension where it will auto-detect the file type from.  You can save with .Rmd or whatever is appropriate.  Alternatively in the bottom right of your source pane you should see "Text File" -> Go ahead and click and change that to R Markdown or R presentation or whatever is appropriate for your particular file.